# Ansible throwing a "Failed to update apt cache: W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely" Error

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I'm very new to Ansible and I'm trying to install kubectl on an EC2 instance (Ubuntu 18.04) for a class.

I have ran the playbook and it went well until it hit task 4 then threw the following error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FEEA9169307EA071 NO_PUBKEY 8B57C5C2836F4BEB, E:The repository 'https://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial InRelease' is not signed."}

It now throws the same error on task 1 whenever I try to run it again. Can someone advise me on how to fix this?

This is the playbook I have written, it's based on an exercise I completed for installing Docker using Ansible and the commands given to me for installing kubectl:

```
- name: A playbook to install kubectl on a VM
  hosts: localhost
  user: ubuntu
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: 1. Update APT Package Manager
    apt:
      update_cache: yes

  - name: 2. Install dependency packages
    apt:
      name={{ item }}
    with_items:
      - apt-transport-https
      - ca-certificates
      - curl
      - gnupg-agent
      - software-properties-common

  - name: 3. Get APT Key
    shell:
      cmd: curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
      cmd: echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list

  - name: 4. Update Packages
    apt:
      update_cache: yes

  - name: 5. Install Kubectl
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
      name: kubectl
```

Comment: This is probably failing because of the configuration of the linux instance where you are running this command, as task 1 is just doing `apt update`. You must have a missconfigured APT repo... well not missconfigured, but there's no GPG key. I assume you are running this on your local machine since the host is `localhost`. You probably need to delete the file or entry that currently has the APT repo `kubernetes-xenial` in `/etc/apt/*`.

Comment: Task 3 cannot work. Only your second command is excited. The curl does not happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the part

```
- name: 3. Get APT Key
    shell:
      cmd: curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
      cmd: echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
```

The [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html)_module will only execute the second `cmd`. Ansible can only pass one of the parameters to the module, the last one.

To [download files from HTTPS to node](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html) you may use the [`get_url`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html#examples)_module, followed by an [`apt_key`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_key_module.html)_module task to [add an apt key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_key_module.html#examples).

```
- name: Download apt key
  get_url:
    url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
    dest: /tmp # or /etc/pki/rpm-gpg depending on the infrastructure

- name: Add a key from a file
  ansible.builtin.apt_key:
    file: /tmp/apt-key.gpg
    state: present
```

You could also add it by

```
- name: Add an Apt signing key, uses whichever key is at the URL
  ansible.builtin.apt_key:
    url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
    state: present
```

or if you know the key ID already

```
- name: Add missing Apt signing key by ID from a keyserver
  ansible.builtin.apt_key:
   keyserver: keyserver.ubuntu.com
   id: "{{ KEY_ID }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working with this, I didn't know you couldn't have multiple commands under the shell.