# curl command with pipe not working in Ansible

Tags: docker, curl, ansible, ansible-2.x, gpg-signature

I am trying to execute below command which is part of Docker installation, but it got stuck.

The `gpg` part of the command got stuck, if I remove `gpg` after pipe, it works.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:

    - name: add docker GPG key
      shell: "curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg"
```

Comment: I'm quite sure it is stuck because gpg is waiting for interactive input. See answers below to understand why using shell for this is a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**General Ansible advise:** if you just feed all your command lines in `shell` tasks in Ansible, then you are doing it wrong.
Ansible does have existing module, that are purposed to serve the [idempotency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency) idea that is at the root of Ansible goal and that will greatly simplify all tasks you will try to achieve.

---

This being said, you now have to understand what that specific line of the Docker manual is trying to achieve.

```bash
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg \ 
| gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

This command would add the GPG key of Docker to a trusted keyring on the node, so it can validate the authenticity of the package you will later use in a `package` task.

In more recent versions of Debian and Ubuntu, the key can be passed as is — meaning, without the need to dearmor it — as long as it is used in the `asc` format and defined in the `signed-by` option of the repository.

So, those two task would

1. download the repository key, in `asc` format
2. define the repository along with the `signed-by` option

*Mind that those two tasks require you to gather a minimal set of facts from the nodes in order to resolve the variable `ansible_distribution_release`.*

```yaml
- get_url:
    url:  https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
    dest: /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc
    mode: '0644'

- apt_repository:
    repo: >-
      deb
      [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc]
      https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu
      {{ ansible_distribution_release }}
      stable
```

---

Since version 2.15, there is a new module [`deb822_repository`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/deb822_repository_module.html) that allows for everything to be done in one go — adding the GPG key that would sign the repository along with the repository itself.

*Mind that this one needs the package `python3-debian` installed on the targeted host(s)*

The two tasks described above now sums up to:

```yaml
- deb822_repository:
    name: docker
    types: deb
    uris: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu
    suites: "{{ ansible_distribution_release }}"
    components: stable
    architectures: amd64
    signed_by: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
```

---

Previously, this was the purpose of the module [`apt_key`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_key_module.html), which still exists but since the underlaying `apt-key` command has been deprecated, is just kept for backward compatibility purpose.

Using that module the task to add an apt key would have been:

```yaml
- name: add docker GPG key
  apt_key:
    url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
```

Comment: [apt_key has been deprecated.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_key_module.html). For a general work around, see Example "- name: One way to avoid apt_key once it is removed from your distro..."

Comment: The "General Ansible advise" in concert with the specific explanation of the manual command is a great teaching approach.

Answer (score 3):

**Example for `apt`**

To [download files via HTTPS to your node](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html) you may use the [`get_url`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html#examples)_module, followed by an [`apt_key`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_key_module.html)_module task to [add a key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_key_module.html#examples).

```yaml
- name: Download apt key
  get_url:
    url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
    dest: /tmp # or /etc/pki/rpm-gpg depending on the infrastructure

- name: Add a key from a file
  ansible.builtin.apt_key:
    file: /tmp/gpg
    state: present
```

You could also add it by

```yaml
- name: Add an Apt signing key, uses whichever key is at the URL
  ansible.builtin.apt_key:
    url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
    state: present
```

You may need to use other modules or task for `gpg` or `keyring`.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Downloading and adding key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70323221/6771046)

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem today, as I don't want to use the `apt_key` module because `apt-key` command, that the module use under the hood, is deprecated. I was following the same approach than you.

As @Zeitounator mention, the issue is caused because gpg is running in the nteractive mode and waiting a confirmation, and I'm sure that is because the destination file already exist (probably because you run the task before), so it's asking you to override that file.
So the solution in this case is to use the `creates` option in the `shell` module pointing to the path where you are storing the gpg key. Whit this the task would not run again if the file exist. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-creates

```yaml
- name: add docker GPG key
  shell: |
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg |\
    gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
  creates: /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

Comment: Yes, this exact problem I faced. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[apt_key has been deprecated.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_key_module.html). For a general work around,
Ansible Example "- name: One way to avoid apt_key once it is removed from your distro..." suggests using a combination of `ansible.builtin.get_url` and `ansible.builtin.apt_repository`.

Also note that the Example indicates that "armored keys should use .asc extension, binary should use .gpg". Although the [Docker Ubuntu installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) refers to `docker.gpg`, I used `docker.asc` because the Docker installation instructions imply that the key is armored (i.e., they require running `gpg --dearmor`).

```
- name: install Docker | Add Docker’s official GPG key
  become: yes
  block:
    - name: docker | add apt key
      ansible.builtin.get_url:
        url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
        dest: /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc

    - name: docker | add apt source
      ansible.builtin.apt_repository:
        repo: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu {{ ansible_distribution_release }} stable
        state: present
```

Also see [How can I manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d with ansible playbook since apt-key is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585303/how-can-i-manage-keyring-files-in-trusted-gpg-d-with-ansible-playbook-since-apt)